# BOT for company use

Tags: botframework, skype-for-business

I have a BOT that answers questions for sales people, but I need to make sure that only users in my company's Azure Active Directory are able to access the BOT.  Is there a way to only allow Skype for business users and authorize based on their access token?

Thanks

Terry

Comment: So you want your bot to be able to receive messages on the Facebook, Skype, etc. channels only from users that are also registered on Skype for Business?

Comment: I am fine with the user coming from any client app as long as they can prove that they are using their "work" account (not facebook, microsoft account, etc).  I mentioned Skype for business since it integrates with the Azure AD and I making an assumption that I'd be able to get their user's token from AAD.

Answer (score 0):

You could send a link to the user that takes her to an AAD authentication page, with the callback URL pointing to your service. Once you get the callback, set the user's state (in UserBotData) to authenticated. I believe [**this**](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code/) page can help you in the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

### METHOD 1 (Oauth)

Step 1: if `context.PrivateConversationData.GetValue("authenticated")`is **false**

Step 2: Return authentication link to the chat (including **callbackurl** in the url)

> Note: in step 2, you might want to include `ResumptionCookie` to enable the ability to resume the conversation later.
>
> **In botframework sample code, they have an excellent demo** (https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Samples/SimpleFacebookAuthBot/Controllers/OAuthCallbackController.cs)

Step 3: When user is authenticated and being redirected to the **callbackurl** you've set, set the `context.PrivateConversationData.Setvalue("authenticated", true);`

### METHOD 2 (Inline Authentication)

Step 1: check if user is authenticated (similar to above)

Step 2: ask user to input his **ADID** in your **Azure Active Directory**

Step 3: find his email or any unique identifier, generate OTP, send to his mobile number

Step 4: Verify the OTP sent by user

Step 5: Set PrivateConversationData (similar to above).

> Google has an excellent library to create & verify OTP (https://www.nuget.org/packages/GoogleAuthenticator/1.0.0)

Answer (score 0):

You can authenticate your bot's users against their corporate AAD account using a library like [botauth](https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/botauth/).

Here's an example bot. https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/botauth/blob/master/examples/aadv2/app.js